# Whatz wrong in this query, can any one re-edit this query to delete whole record from table1 using username from gridview cell 4 ...?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
   Whatz wrong in this query, can any one re-edit this query to delete whole record from table1 using username from gridview cell 4 ... ?
```

***HOW TO DELETE RECORD IF I USE USERID AS UNIQUE IDENTIFIER DATATYPE AND PRIMARY KEY***

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

     Dim con As New SqlConnection
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                Try
                    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE UserName =" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(4).ToString
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error while Deleting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Delete Records")
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know VB.NET but it looks like your `CommandText` will be:

`DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE UserName = foobar`

as opposed to

`DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE UserName = 'foobar'`

... and it looks like I was beaten to it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE UserName ='" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(4).ToString & "'"
```

and secondly, to avoid [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you should rather use [SqlParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)